# How to get data from Business Central?

Tags: c#, web-services, nav, dynamics-business-central

I have made a C#-project where I am trying to connect to my Business Central cloud sandbox.

In Business Central, I have made an extension with a new codeunit, which has a function that I call "MHSTest". It just returns a text.

In Visual Studio, I have made the service reference that connects to the SOAP URL in Business Central. So I can see the name of my function, "MHSTest", in Visual Studio.

When I write this in Visual Studio, I get an error, because it tries to connect anonymously:

```
var client = new MHSTest.CSharpCodeunit_PortClient();
myTextBox.Text = client.MHSTest();
```

---

If I try the below instead, I get an error message saying that "https" is not valid. It has to be "http".

```
string endpoint = "">api.businesscentral.dynamics.com/.../CSharpCodeunit";
var binding = new BasicHttpBinding();
binding.Security.Mode = BasicHttpSecurityMode.TransportCredentialOnly;
binding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Windows;
binding.MaxBufferSize = 999999;
binding.MaxReceivedMessageSize = 999999;

var client = new MHSTest.CSharpCodeunit_PortClient(binding, new EndpointAddress(endpoint));

myTextBox.Text = client.MHSTest();
```

---

How do I connect to Business Central and get (or set) data?

App.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
<startup>
<supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1" />
</startup>
<system.serviceModel>
<bindings>
<basicHttpBinding>
<binding name="Debitorer_Binding">
<security mode="Transport" />
</binding>
<binding name="Debitorer_Binding1" />
<binding name="CSharpCodeunit_Binding">
<security mode="Transport" />
</binding>
<binding name="CSharpCodeunit_Binding1" />
</basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<client>
<endpoint address="api.businesscentral.dynamics.com/.../2999befa-1255-4304-a79a-67de0e24f090/Sandbox/WS/CRONUS%20Danmark%20A%252FS/Page/Debitorer?tenant=msneua5672t92712555&amp;aid=FIN"
binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="Debitorer_Binding"
contract="BCCustomer.Debitorer_Port" name="Debitorer_Port" />
<endpoint address="api.businesscentral.dynamics.com/.../2999befa-1255-4304-a79a-67de0e24f090/Sandbox/WS/CRONUS%20Danmark%20A%252FS/Codeunit/CSharpCodeunit?tenant=msneua5672t92712555&amp;aid=FIN"
binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="CSharpCodeunit_Binding"
contract="MHSTest.CSharpCodeunit_Port" name="CSharpCodeunit_Port" />
</client>
</system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is solved. I just needed to add this code after defining my client variable:

System.ServiceModel.Security.UserNamePasswordClientCredential cre = client.ClientCredentials.UserName;

cre.UserName = "  ";
cre.Password = "  ";

Comment: The forum removed what I had written after Username and Password.
They should be set to the user name and web key from Business Central.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Export-NAVData cmdlet to export data from a Business Central database. You can export company-specific data, and you can choose to include global data, application data, and application objects. When you export data from a Business Central database, the data is stored in a file with the extension .

Comment: Thanks Sam.
But as you can read, my problem was solved in july 2020 - and my program should (and can) read data from Business Central and write data to Business Central at once one record at a time.

Best regards,

Morten